# Booklet creation El Capitan

Tags: applescript, automator, pdf

Since I passed to El Capitan, good'ol Create Booklet 1.2 (http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/21068/create-booklet) won't work anymore (it used to be free, but is now paid for). All the available booklet creation programs cost something and I simply can't afford them.

So I went on a hunt to use Automator and/or AppleScript. I only found this site which does not seem to be maintained anymore, I also tried to contact the webmaster/owner, but none of the available e-mail addresses work (they came back with a delivery failure): http://automatorworld.com/archives/create-pdf-booklet/

Does anyone have an idea how to create such an applet for Mac?

What would be the (mathematical?) formula and/or the routine to start such a project with Automator/AppleScript?

Comment: One could create an Automator Action with Xcode.  This, in turn, could be used in any Automator service or workflow.  [Apple Dev documentation seems to be a bit old](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/AutomatorConcepts/Automator.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001674-SW1), but should work in principle.

Answer (score 1):

I found a method that works for me. In this thread (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7253885) I discovered that you can create a print plugin in Automator that will do close to what you want.

Go to Automator and first create a new print plugin.

Next search for Rename PDF Documents and add-drag that into the workflow. You will not actually need to change anything or use the rename tool. It was what fixed the problem in the other thread.

Last search for Create Booklet and add-drag that below the rename section.

Finally save the print plugin.

It should allow you to go through the PDF menu on the print dialog and allow you to create a booklet on the Desktop. You'll just have to go through the extra step to open it and and print it out.

Hope it helps.

The whole print plugin should look like this:

[image: Create Booklet 2 Print Plugin]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for this. I was v. upset to find Create Booklet didn't work in El Cap.

Very minor addition to have the booklet open and then move to trash if, like me, you don't usually want to keep the resulting booklet file.

Thanks again...

David.
[image: Screenshot]